# C++: Forward class definition required to compile some code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, forward-declaration

I am programming a small game in C++ as an exercise, and I've come across a conundrum. 
The basic idea is that a `Level` has a `vector` of `Entity`, and each `Entity` instance knows which level it belongs to. Pretty straightforward so far.

I was getting some nasty compile errors in my Entity class as it couldn't figure out what `Level` was. A simple **forward class declaration** right before the declaration of `Entity` easily fixed that. However, I am already including `"Level.h"` in `"Entity.h"`. And `Level` and `Entity` are both declared and defined in the same namespace.

Note: `Entity.h` also includes `Level.h`.

```
#include "Level.h"

namespace GameNS {

  // Required, otherwise the compiler complains
  class Level;

  class Entity
  {
  public:
  ...
```

Shouldn't the compiler already know what `Level` is, by the time it reaches `Entity`?

Comment: Does ``Level.h`` include ``Entity.h``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that's not how the C++ compiler works. What it does is it basically passes through the files one translation unit at a time. A TU is, loosely put, an implementation file with all its includes.

If you have include guards in `Level.h` and `Entity.h` (you probably do) and they include each other, one of them, depending on the order, will be left out by the compiler, and one of the names won't be declared.

As a rule of thumb, use forward-declarations when you can, and `include`s where you must.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for the explanation! I find it interesting that you can make a file stop compiling simply by including it in a file it includes (this is exactly the process I went through when I ended up with this error).

Comment: @AndreiBârsan yeah, cpp is fun like that.

Comment: Do you happen to know of a good book that explains these sort of things? Stuff like the C++ Primer don't say too much about the actual compilation process. Or should I just start poking around with g++'s source code?

Comment: @AndreiBârsan C++ is so complex, I doubt there's one book explaining everything, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list is a good start.